# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_ndarray' while reading parquet files in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, fastparquet

I am trying to read the parquet files using pandas and fastparquet engine, like below. Getting the error.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_parquet("path/to/parquet_file/", engine='fastparquet')
```

Error:
File "C:\venv_3.10\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimelike.py", line 758, in _unbox
other = other._ndarray
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_ndarray'